# jQuery mobile page transition is always fade

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

This example of page transitions from jQuery works in Chrome http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/pages/#docs-transitions.html

But when I try it myself with this code it always uses the fade effect. In Firefox it does work. When building this with phonegap it doesn't work on iOS and it doesn't work on Android.

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery/jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery/jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
</head>

<body id="body">
    <div id="page1" data-role="page">
        <a id="my_link" href="#page2" data-role="button" data-transition="slide">
            click me
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="page2" data-role="page">
        <div>
            page2
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

I looked into the jquery mobile javascript file and saw it called $.mobile._maybeDegradeTransition in the changepage function. This function checks if the browser supports csstransform3d. Chrome returns false to this. When I change the code to always return true Chrome just does the transition.

Answer (score 0):

According to the JQuery Mobile site:

> Only seeing fade transitions? To view all transition types, you must be on a browser that supports 3D transforms. By default, devices that lack 3D support (such as Android 2.x) will fallback to "fade" for all transition types. This behavior is configurable (see below).

source: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/pages/page-transitions.html